# SPARQL query: how to get line and char number from EARL document?

Tags: semantic-web, sparql, jena

This might be a rather novice question but RDF graphs and sparql queries just confuse me. 
This is the relevant part of an (EARL, Evaluation And Report Language) RDF file that I need to search:

```
<earl:Assertion>
<earl:subject rdf:nodeID="A1"/>
<earl:assertedBy rdf:nodeID="A2"/>
<earl:test rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_2"/>
<earl:mode rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/ns/earl#automatic"/>
<earl:result>
  <earl:TestResult>
    <earl:pointer>
      <pnt:EquivalentPointers>
        <pnt:groupPointer>
          <pnt:LineCharPointer>
            <pnt:charNumber rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#positiveInteger"
            >108</pnt:charNumber>
            <pnt:lineNumber rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#positiveInteger"
            >9</pnt:lineNumber>
          </pnt:LineCharPointer>
        </pnt:groupPointer>
        <pnt:groupPointer>
          <pnt:CharOffsetPointer>
            <pnt:offset rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#positiveInteger"
            >935</pnt:offset>
          </pnt:CharOffsetPointer>
        </pnt:groupPointer>
      </pnt:EquivalentPointers>
    </earl:pointer>
    <earl:outcome rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/ns/earl#failed"/>
    <dct:description rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
    >A space character is missing before '/&gt;'.</dct:description>
  </earl:TestResult>
</earl:result>
</earl:Assertion>
```

What I want to get from this excerpt: lineNumber (and charNumber), the fact that the earl:outcome was failed, and the description. So far all I was able to get was the line number, the result however gave the line number +"^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#positiveInteger". I don't know why this happened.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you tried on: http://answers.semanticweb.com/

Comment: Can you please show what queries you have tried so far?

Comment: @YMomb: Jena and semantic web questions are welcome, and answered, on StackOverflow as well as answers.semanticweb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following query pulls out all failed results from your sample (note that I had to make up a URI for `pnt:`, since you didn't say what it was and it's not listed at [prefix.cc](http://prefix.cc)):

```
prefix pnt: <http://example.org/pnt#>
prefix earl: <http://www.w3.org/ns/earl#>
prefix dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

select ?result ?desc ?charNo ?lineNo {
  ?assert a earl:Assertion;
          earl:result ?result.

  ?result earl:outcome earl:failed;
          earl:pointer/pnt:groupPointer ?gpt;
          dct:description ?desc.

  ?gpt pnt:charNumber ?charNo;
       pnt:lineNumber ?lineNo.
}
```

This query gives the following result in plain text:

```
$ arq --graph=./src/main/resources/earl.rdf --file=./src/main/resources/earl.sparql
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| result | desc                                                                                              | charNo                                                    | lineNo                                                  |
====================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
| _:b0   | "A space character is\n          missing before '/>'."^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> | "108"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#positiveInteger> | "9"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#positiveInteger> |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The two numbers you want are datatyped with XSD types, according to the RDF sample you provided. The `^^` decorations simply express the datatypes using the Turtle syntax. You can see this clearly if we select output in JSON instead:

```
$ arq --graph=./src/main/resources/earl.rdf --file=./src/main/resources/earl.sparql --results=json
{
  "head": {
    "vars": [ "result" , "desc" , "charNo" , "lineNo" ]
  } ,
  "results": {
    "bindings": [
      {
        "result": { "type": "bnode" , "value": "b0" } ,
        "desc": { "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" , "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "A space character is\n          missing before '/>'." } ,
        "charNo": { "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#positiveInteger" , "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "108" } ,
        "lineNo": { "datatype": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#positiveInteger" , "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "9" }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Ian thank you very much. Works like a charm. By the way, the pnt URI is: `http://www.w3.org/2009/pointers#`
There is still something annoying though. I am using the Jena framework to query the file and while I do get the correct result, I also get a bunch of errors and warnings > Base URI is null, but there are relative URIs to resolve.
Relative URIs are not permitted in RDF. The base is not defined in the document. Where do I define it and how would it look like?
Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, relative URI's are indeed not permitted in RDF. There are two ways to resolve them: either ensure you have an `xml:base` in your input XML document, or pass the base URI as the second parameter of the `Model.read(String url, String base, String lang) ` call.

Comment: Thanks! Went with the second option and the errors have gone away.